# Windows Cannot Use SSH Tunnel Proxy

Tags: networking, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I need help getting to the bottom of an issue using an SSH tunnel as SOCKS5 proxy (127.0.0.1:9090) in Windows 11 22H2.

I can establish an SSH tunnel using WSL, Putty or the Bitvise (BTW great) client. It doesn't make a difference.

I know the tunnel is properly established, because I can `curl --socks5 localhost:9090 -O https://example.org` from the WSL and the cmd CLIs. But I cannot use the tunnel in Windows outside of the cli (WSL or cmd), no matter if I set the proxy via a Chrome extension, via browser settings or via the native Windows settings. I get `No internet - ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED`. It doesn't matter which server I tunnel into: it only works from both CLIs. It doesn't matter which browser I use.

Disabling Windows firewall or Malwarebytes entirely does not help. Changing the proxy port to something else doesn't help. Wireshark shows normal flow and some very infrequent *Out of Order* errors when using the CLI to download a large file, so there are no general networking errors. When trying to use the proxy from the browser, Wireshark shows nothing. Not a single packet in any direction.

This is not a DNS issue, as http://1.1.1.1/help also doesn't load.

This same tunnel setup used to work a couple months ago. I have probably installed some software since, along with Windows updates. The two pieces of SW which are more network related have been uninstalled. I can't keep uninstalling everything to find out what the issue is.

**UPDATE1:** A reboot brought back the tunnel at slow speeds, so most websites will end up in `ERR_TIMED_OUT`

**UPDATE2:** A Windows Network Reset followed by the mandatory reboot did not help.

**UPDATE3 - Narrowing Down the Issue:** Turns out when the tunnel is initiated from WSL using `ssh -D 9090 -N example.org` it doesn't exit properly, despite the terminal showing it does after a CTRL-C. `netstat -ant` also doesn't show any process listening on 9090. So when I try to run the tunnel for a 2nd time, it gets stuck because the previous process is still attached to the port, all while the CLI shows no errors on the 2nd attempt. When the tunnel is initiated via Bitvise (and prob also Putty), it can be shutdown and restarted as needed.

**What should I look into next?** is no longer relevant. I will place an answer here to close the question, unless someone has an idea of what I should try to use so that the tunnel closes properly when initiated from WSL (which after all this time tshooting this I don't really care much, I will keep using Bitvise for tunneling)

Comment: For those voting `close`, which details would you like to see? ask questions. I'm obviously not lazy.

Comment: Given that a reboot fixed it, the problem could have been a unique aspect of your system or it could be something both more specific and broadly applicable. The difficulty is that with the issue resolved, there may not be a way to tell which it is. One of the goals of this site is questions and answers are broadly applicable. Yes, answering questions is a goal, but another higher goal is to build a more or less complete compendium of problems and solutions, which does mean that a problem that cannot be answered with detail and specificity CAN attract close votes regardless of its own merit.

Comment: A reboot didn't fix it. the issue has become more specific, pls see update3, @music2myear

Comment: Cool, even more reasons not to close it.